# How to redirect users to another domain .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Server by default redirects users who type example.com/folder to example.com/folder/

Is there any way to change that (for example when they go to example.com/folder to redirect to  otherexample.com/folder/). But this has to affect all folders but exclude the root. Also the code should do nothing when they type example.com/folder/.

**Edit**

Also the code should not affect images and all other files (or better say, if the requested document has file extension), just folders.

example:

```
should affect : example.com/folder
              : example.com/folder/folder

but should not : example.com
               : example.com/forum (but only forum, only this folder)
               : example.com/folder/
               : example.com/folder/.
               : example.com/folder/folder/
               : example.com/image.png
               : example.com/something.something
               : example.com/something.
               : example.com/.something
```

**Edit**

And an other edit:
Let's say we found the .htaccess code (the 1st answer below). How do I make it work for all my domain and website expect my blog (example.com/blog) which I don't want to have redirections like whole my website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Server by default redirects users who type example.com/folder to
> example.com/folder/

That's done by [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) for several good reasons, all of which are explained in the [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) documentation. You could use `DirectorySlash Off` to turn that behaviour off, but it is generally NOT a good idea to do that, unless you have VERY good and valid reasons to do so.

However, having said that, what you've described in your question can be handled by [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) alone. First, you need to check if the requested resource is a directory. It needs to be a physical directory inside your `DocumentRoot`.

```
RewriteCond   %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}  -d
```

It is vitally important to also apply `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`, otherwise the directory check won't work.

---

- '-d' (is directory)

  Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.

---

Second, you need to ignore all requests to directories that actually do have a trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}                  !/$
```

Now you've filtered down to just the resources you want to redirect to another domain: directories without a trailing slash. Everything else (directories with trailing slashes, images, etc.) is not even in the game at this point. Time for the actual redirect.

```
RewriteRule   ^   http://other.com%{REQUEST_URI}/ [redirect=temp,last]
```

You might want to change your mind later on about the redirection, so you should use temporary redirects (a.k.a. [302 Found](http://httpstatus.es/302)) instead of permanent ones (a.k.a. [301 Moved Permanently](http://httpstatus.es/301)). The `last` tells mod_rewrite to stop all further processing.

And here's the final product:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond   %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}  -d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}                  !/$

RewriteRule   ^   http://other.com%{REQUEST_URI}/ [redirect=temp,last]
```

Comment: One more question if you let me ask you.
Is there any code which will not allow this code affect my blog located in example.com/blog .

Comment: Yes, add `RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/blog`. Now how about that bounty?

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherexample.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: but I don't wan't it to redirect images and other stuff, just folders

Comment: So, I am saying, it does the job, but it does more that is not good. If you can, please make it more specific and folder only.

Answer (score 1):

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/

# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 302 / http://mt-example.com/

# This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/

# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html

# Provide Specific Index Page (Set the default handler)
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

[Read more here for RewriteEngine method](http://www.ksl-consulting.co.uk/301-redirect-examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you need

```
Redirect 301 /directory http://www.newdomain.com
```

just change directory with your folder name

Comment: if folder names are same it will make an infinite redirect loop

Answer (score 1):

For  :  www.newdomain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For  : olddomain.com to newdomain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```